# Dates appearing as decimals in R plot

Tags: r, date, zoo

I’m trying to plot some data with month data along the x-axis. Unfortunately the months are appearing as decimals. Any ideas?

```
library(zoo)  # Requires the zoo library.
theMonths <- as.yearmon(c( "Mar 2011", "Apr 2011", "May 2011", "Jun 2011", "Jul 2011", "Aug 2011", "Sep 2011", "Oct 2011", "Nov 2011", "Dec 2011", "Jan 2012", "Feb 2012"))
x <- c(1:12)
plot(theMonths,x,axes=FALSE)
axis(1,theMonths)
# Why do the dates appear on the axis as decimals?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how the `yearmon` class objects are structured:

```
dput(theMonths)
structure(c(2011.16666666667, 2011.25, 2011.33333333333, 2011.41666666667, 
2011.5, 2011.58333333333, 2011.66666666667, 2011.75, 2011.83333333333, 
2011.91666666667, 2012, 2012.08333333333), class = "yearmon")
```

You can see that it stores these decimal values, and a call to `as.numeric` gives:

```
[1] 2011.167 2011.250 2011.333 2011.417 2011.500 2011.583 2011.667 2011.750 2011.833
[10] 2011.917 2012.000 2012.083
```

If you look at `axis`, the second argument is `at` and that is what you have called. When you don't specify `labels` it must take the `at` values as numerics. If you also specify labels the problem is solved:

```
axis(1,theMonths,theMonths)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in `axis.yearmon` which is fixed in the development version of zoo.  Try this:

```
library(zoo)
source("http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/zoo/R/yearmon.R?revision=916&root=zoo")
z <- zooreg(1:12, as.yearmon("2011-03"), freq = 12)
plot(z, cex = .8)
```

ADDED: Since this question was answered zoo 1.7-7 has appeared on CRAN and it includes the above functionality so the development version is no longer needed.

[image: output of sample plot.zoo using yearmon index class]

Comment: It appears that he is calling `axis` rather than `axis.yearmon`

Comment: @James: If you call `axis` with a yearmon classed object it gets dispatched to `axis.yearmon` .... it's the Way of R.

Comment: @DWin I understand thats how it generally works, but I get different behaviour when I use `axis(1,theMonths)` compared to `zoo:::axis.yearmon(1,theMonths)`

Comment: I don't, although the now-fixed bug does show up in both instances. I was guessing looking at the code that it was in the format string that said `format <- c("%Y", "%b")` and should have been `format <- "%Y "%b"`. (But testing shows I was wrong.)

Comment: @James, There may be a problem with `axis` but possibly because of difficulties in backwards compatibility `Axis` was added to R some time ago (years) and it would be better to use that and even more concise to just use the bug fix in zoo and let `plot.zoo` call the appropriate routine.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck `Axis` does the method dispatch properly for me, though the syntax is slightly different.